# If user didn't login, will cron job be executed?

Tags: cron

I set up crontab to run the daily jobs.

Sometimes it failed and forever loop/work in the same directory.

The next day, the crontab will run the same script in the same directory.

It is expected to finish work in every evening, but now when one day failed to finished, it will be mixed up with the work in the next day.

I plan to do a (daily) reboot (ex: 4PM) before the daily cron job (5PM), will the cron jobs be executed after reboot without user login?

#Note
It is clear the problem is from the script ( and what the script is doing)  not about the crontab.

Comment: Yes, cron jobs run whether or not anyone's logged in. But it's impossible to say if rebooting will fix the problem. You'll need to troubleshoot the script to find out what's going wrong in order to fix it properly. There are canonical questions about cron job troubleshooting on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) and [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working).

Comment: Not sure why a full reboot is required to terminate one rogue script. Have the script record its name and pid in a file in /tmp. Set up a cron for 16:45 which checks for the previous day's job, kills it, and removes the /tmp file. Pids can get re-used, hence the job should remove its own /tmp file when it exits successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the `cron` daemon is running at the time, cron jobs will be executed as per schedule regardless of user login.

You have described that your cron job does not finish/complete work as expected.  This is not likely to be an issue with `cron` (as the script is triggered correctly), but may be a logical error in your shell script.

You can troubleshoot the problem by capturing the output from the script. One approach is to let the script output the details to stdout/stderr, and then configure `cron`'s email settings. `cron` will capture the output and send it to you. Another approach is to do the logging yourself, inside the script - create a log file and redirect stdout/stderr from all commands to that file.

If the failure only occurs under specific conditions, you can incorporate checks for that into your script. You can check for the exit status of key commands and report a failure when appropriate.

Lastly, a note about the reboot. If the system is not running at the scheduled time, `cron` will not execute the job even after the system comes back online. If this is the scenario you have, look into [`anacron`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron).